# Is Italian best suitable for study as a foreign language for school students?

Tags: language-comparison, italian

From this year, school students in Iran could choose Italian as their foreign language. In the past, they only could choose English, French or German, but from this year they also can choose Spanish, Italian, Russian or Mandarin.

In least developed countries like Iran, the main purpose for learning a foreign language is using it as a developed modern language with sufficient resources in contemporary science.

So how much Italian could fulfill this need — especially in comparison to English, French and German?

Comment: You refer "the main purpose for learning a foreigner language". Are you sure that the Iranian government sets this very purpose, and not another? What if, for example, the government has another idea in mind? Could it be simply a political gesture to please Italy? For example, schoolchildren in Soviet Russia (my parents) of 1930-40s mostly studied German, not English, due to the political alliance between Communist Russia and Nazi Germany.

Comment: This question is not relevant to language learning per se.

Answer (score -2):

Well, most scientific articles are written in English, so it would probably be  better to study that language in your specific circumstance.